# Do all the D' girls have dragon "mates"?

Tags: unlimited-fafnir

Some of Yuu's classmates are shown to have dragon "partners"/"suitors" (to avoid a more heavy term), and the plot runs around avoiding having the dragon meet the designated girl.

I am talking about when a dragon comes for a girl and her Ryuumon glows.

Examples are Iris and Leviathan, Tear and Basilisk, the girl Mitsuki killed (she turned into a dragon in the backstory).

But the school has dozens of D girls. Are there that much dragon beasts rampaging around?

Comment: Can you cite an instance of this dragon "partner"? I can't quite remember where this happened.

Comment: @nhahtdh Iris & Leviathan, the horned redhead and basilisk, the girl Mononobe killed after she turned dragon... from your comment I think "mate" would be a better wording.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not, as I cannot imagine that Yggdrasil is in the same realm as mankind, I would imagine there are multiple or perhaps even an infinite amount of realms. That would also explain the sudden appearance of the Dragons.

Unfortunately I have no real evidence of this being the case. My comment is based on mere assumptions after watching the aired episodes of the anime series.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this?